# Conditional CSS tags for IE showing in page

Tags: css

I've added the conditional CSS include tags for IE into the head of my document:

```
<!--[if lt IE8]>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %>
<![endif]-->
```

Unfortunately this causes them to show up in the page when it's rendered in IE.

How can I banish them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right syntax is

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %>
<![endif]-->
```

Note the space between 'IE' and '8'.  Not sure if this is your problem - but try it.  Check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for specifics of the conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

The space should definitely be there. But that doesn't explain why it shows up.

Are you sure you didn't escape the brackets at the start of the comment? e.g. &lt;!-- instead of <!-- ?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional comments are very spacing sensitive. Follow the spacing in Microsoft's documentation slavishly. In this case, add a space after the `<!--`and before the `-->`.